# Chrome : type in textboxes instead of selecting them

Tags: google-chrome, selection

not sure what is happening but quite often i go to highlight/doubleclick text in a textbox in Google's Chrome browser, and somehow the textbox itself gets selected. I have to redo my selection so it selects the text inside...

It is hard to explain but is it possible that whenever I have a textbox selected, when I type, the text I type goes in the box (instead of nowhere)?

It seems like a rather uh, silly/stupid question, but it would save me time and make my browsing more efficient. I can work a mouse and type just as well as anyone else, Chrome is the only browser I have trouble in where it likes to select the textboxes instead of the text inside the textboxes. I love Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the textbox suddenly highlighting around edges, I'm guessing that this how Chrome tells you that you're working in a textbox/textarea. I've tried duplicating what you're saying with my own version of Chrome 3 and I can not duplicate the issue that you have described.

Hope this helps you.